# iterating over python mysql output

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tuples, mysql-python

the code is

```
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="something",database="mrbean")

mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("select * from store")

myresult=mycursor.fetchall()

for i in myresult:
    print(i)
```

this gives the output correctly but if i want only one row
i did like this `print(i)[1]`  this gave me an error why?

ERROR-

```
(2010, 'Note Book', 25, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sajim/Documents/python random programes/python mysql.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(i)[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `print(myresult[1])`? Because you want the first row of the result?

Comment: no that gave all the 2nd column data in every row

Comment: Then you could change it to `print(myresult[0])`, and leave out the ` for i in myresult:`

Comment: that gave me the output correctly but if i wanted to iterate using a for loop and print only a certain row . That is not possible?

Comment: say if i want to print only the first 5 rows or last 5 rows 

manually writing each one like you said is time consuming

Comment: I downvoted, because of the request "would you care to upvote so that people will answer it quickly – joel.t.mathew 6 mins ago", please say "Thanks!"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  "would you care to upvote so that people will answer it quickly – joel.t.mathew 6 mins ago"

Comment: @Luuk First, the first row would be `myresult[0]` and not `myresult[1]`. Second, if you found the OP's request to upvote the question so it would receive a quick response offensive (it certainly was out of place), the proper response would be a reply explaining the inappropriateness of the request. But the request itself does not invalidate the original post itself and it was therefore inappropriate to give it a close vote or even a downvote because you were miffed (angry).

Comment: @BoobooL It was also because of a change in the question via comment ("that gave me the output correctly but if i wanted to iterate using a for loop and print only a certain row . That is not possible?") It seems hard (generally speaking) to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coded:

```
print(i)[1]
```

That first prints the i<sup>th</sup> value of the `myresult` iterable and then tries to extract element no. 1 from the return value from calling `print`. But the `print` function return `None` and so that is why you get the exception you got.

If you want one row:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
print(myresult)
```

If you have retrieved all the rows:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult[0]) # first row
```

If you want to print the first five rows:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult[0:5]:
    print(row)
```

But it would make more sense just to retrieve only 5 rows using:

```
mycursor.execute("select * from store limit 5")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult:
    print(row)
```

If you want to print the last 5 rows:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult[-5:]:
    print(row)
```

But rather than reading in all the rows, suppose that column `id` was the primary key and the rows were being returned in `id` order (in theory there is no order to a relation, i.e. a table, but in reality the database engine will return the rows in a definite order, which is often in primary key order). Then:

```
mycursor.execute("select * from store order by id desc limit 5")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult:
    print(row)
```